# Upload Theme File on word Press Error occured The link you followed has expired. Please try again

Tags: wordpress-theming, themes

I installed a new wampserver 3.1.3  on my windows 2010 machine and download and place wordpress setup on it.

When I try to add a theme. I am getting the following error.

> The link you followed has expired. 
>   Please try again."

Comment: I changed in the PHP options php.ini file  upload_max_filesize = 1000M
post_max_size = 2000M
memory_limit = 3000M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 180

Comment: Issued has fixed by Configuring these parameters in PHP.ini file

upload_max_filesize = 1000M
post_max_size = 2000M
memory_limit = 3000M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 180

Comment: The issue has fixed by configuring the following parameters in the php.ini file 
Theme uploaded successfully 

    upload_max_filesize = 1000M
     post_max_size = 2000M
    memory_limit = 3000M
    file_uploads = On
    max_execution_time = 180

Comment: A) dont put more infos into comments. B) if your question is answered, either delete it, or write up a **self answer** (if you think that your question / answer will help future readers )